# What is the source code of gcr.io/dms-images/tcp-proxy image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-migration, google-datastream

I am trying to establish a connectivity between Datastream and AlloyDB in Google Cloud.

In the [documentation article](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-postgresql-database#alloydbforpostgresql) it is recommended to set up a TCP proxy due to the inability to have transitive peering between Datastream AlloyDB private network.

It is suggested to use the image `gcr.io/dms-images/tcp-proxy` for the proxy. What is the source code of this image (maybe github repo)? Who maintains this image?

I also found this image is recommended to use in [Google Database Migration Service article](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgresql-to-alloydb/configure-connectivity-tcp-proxy-via-cloud-hosted-vm) (and I assume that dms in the name of the image stands for this service).

Comment: I've pulled the docker image and looked myself into it using this tool https://github.com/wagoodman/dive. It installs HAProxy, netcat, copies there configs and a startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker image (and tcp proxy itself) is maintained by a Google team.

The GitHub repo here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/alloydb-auth-proxy has both the source for the proxy itself, as well as the Dockerfiles.